# Why opacity applied to select is not applied to options?

Tags: css

Opacity applied to `<select>` is not applied to `<option>` which is a child element, why?

This feature allows to make custom dropdown lists that look consistent on different platforms but at the same time preserve native behaviour of the options. [Example one](http://jsfiddle.net/2k02qtus/), [example two](http://guitar.creator.nz/).

I wonder how reliable this behaviour is. Is it a standard or a trick?

```css
select {
  opacity: 0;
  border: none;
  height: 24px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -24px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
span {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Click me</span>
  <select>
    <option>Opt 1</option>
    <option>Opt 2</option>
    <option>Opt 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding of the spec, this is not reliable.

[§3.2. Transparency: the ‘opacity’ property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency) says `opacity` also affects the content of the element (emphasis mine):

> Conceptually, after the element (**including its descendants**) is
>   rendered into an RGBA offscreen image, the opacity setting specifies
>   how to blend the offscreen rendering into the current composite
>   rendering.

However, `select` elements are replaced elements. And a [replaced element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html#replaced-element) is

> An element whose content is outside the scope of the CSS formatting
>   model [...]
>   The content of replaced elements is not considered in the
>   CSS rendering model.

Therefore, `opacity` might not affect the content of a replaced element. But it might affect it too.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is what I was looking for, only I hoped for a bit more certainty. The behaviour I described seems to be consistent across different platforms and I've seen it used on some high profile websites. I wonder what browser makers take into account when implementing this feature, I guess it's the second statement that you quoted about the 'replaced element'. If there are no other responses any time soon then I'll accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

That's default behaviour by your browser which you can't influence with just the `<select>`. But you can use custom select boxes, one of them is the [jQuery UI Selectmenu](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/).

But keep in mind that mobile devices are optimized for the `<select>` element and using jQuery plugins it might not look as expected. However, it's a good start when you want to customize your select options.

Comment: The technique I described is mobile friendly, it shows a custom looking label, when you click or tap on it you get a native list of options. My question was if setting opacity of the 'select' element to 0 was safe. What if some future browser implementation will set the 'options' opacity to 0 as well thus breaking this custom dropdown trick.

Comment: It's mobile friendly, but you will not get customized items any time soon. If you really want that, then a jQuery plugin is the only option. You should stick to what browsers *can* do right now and not so much what *could* be in the future.